# HTML-5 : video tag. Video not playing

Tags: html, html5-video

I was trying use/test video tag of HTML-5. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<video src="./Pilot.avi" controls="controls">
your browser does not support the video tag
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Pilot.avi is stored in the same same directory as this HTML page.

The problem is, I am seeing the controls being displayed but can't play the video.

I tried with,

1) **Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13**

2) **Google Chrome 8.0.552.224**

What could be the problem?

Regards,
Microkernel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a different video format. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table) for reference.

Comment: Yeah it appears to be the problem with the video format... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is that the video format isn't supported by the browsers. I think *think* anything supports AVI containers, and that is before we get into questions about codecs.

Answer (score 1):

.avi container is not supported for HTML5 videos. You'd use other formats, I reccomend VP8 codec (or WebP): is developed by Google and seems to be the future web video format. [Here](http://www.webmproject.org/) you can find more info about it and [here](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/) there is a list of tools you can use to convert your videos in this format.

Yours sincerely, Tancredi.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on your local file system, some browsers may cause a problem.
I was implementing something similar and with Firefox, I couldn't access a video file on my local folder with HTML5 video tag.
But Chrome worked like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The mp4 codec...although controversial among many open source purists...is the best solution and it is supported by just about every browser. In addition it can be used inside a flash container so you can have one file for html5 and a flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a chance that a long video will not play. Try a short video with a 15s or 20s duration. It might work.